# Nested Tab in Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with nested tabs.

If you click on the first tab (ul.plaene li a) What I want is to load the first content of the nested tab.

The html code is usually a PHP loop and I do not want to change the order.

I have found yet no solution to this problem.

```js
$(".stock li:first").addClass("current");
$(".tab-inhalt:first").fadeIn();
$(".tab-content:first").fadeIn();

$(".plaene a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().addClass("current");
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
  var tab = $(this).attr("href");
  $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
  $(tab).fadeIn();
});

$(".reiter a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().addClass("current");
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
  var tab = $(this).attr("href");
  $(".tab-inhalt").not(tab).css("display", "none");
  $(tab).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.tab-content,
.tab-inhalt {
  display: none;
}
.stock li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.stock a {
  color: #0094cd;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}
.stock li.current a {
  color: #4c565c;
}
.plaene a.current {
  color: #4c565c;
}
.tab-alles {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f2f4;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.tab-oben li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f2f4;
}
.tab-oben a {
  color: #0094cd;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="stock">
  <ul class="plaene">
    <li class="current"><a href="#objekttabs1">Untergeschoss</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#objekttabs2">Erdgeschoss</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#objekttabs3">1. Stock</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- End: .stock -->

<div class="tab-alles">
  <div class="tab-oben">
    <div id="objekttabs1" class="tab-content">
      <ul class="reiter">
        <li class="current"><a href="#wohnunginhalt1">Gesamtfläche</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="objekttabs2" class="tab-content">
      <ul class="reiter">
        <li class=""><a href="#wohnunginhalt2">Gesamtfläche</a></li>
        <li><a href="#wohnunginhalt3">Wohnung 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#wohnunginhalt4">Wohnung 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="objekttabs3" class="tab-content">
      <ul class="reiter">
        <li><a href="#wohnunginhalt5">Wohnung 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- End: .tab-oben -->
  
  <div class="tab-inhalt-all">
    <div id="wohnunginhalt1" class="tab-inhalt">
      <div class="content">Content1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="wohnunginhalt2" class="tab-inhalt">
      <div class="content">Content2</div>
    </div>
    <div id="wohnunginhalt3" class="tab-inhalt">
      <div class="content">Content3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="wohnunginhalt4" class="tab-inhalt">
      <div class="content">Content4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="wohnunginhalt5" class="tab-inhalt">
      <div class="content">Content5</div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- End: .tab-inhalt-all -->
```

Comment: Hi @Domenikus. Welcome to SO. It seems your question needs some editing. You have a lot of code there. Consider to remove what is not completely relevant to the question. Also it's not completely clear what your question is. If you need some tips on how to ask, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Ok thanks, I shortened the code

Comment: @DomenikusGruber it looks like you might have missed a closing tab for `.tab-alles` - I don't think it's relevant to your issue, but wanted to mention it.  Also, not entirely sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to add is `$("li:first a",tab).click()` at the end of your `$(".plaene a").click()` function:

```
$(".plaene a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().addClass("current");
  $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
  var tab = $(this).attr("href");
  $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
  $(tab).fadeIn();
  $("li:first a",tab).click();
});
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u00u9fo2/)